# Prestashop CMS configuration

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop

Hi I'm totally new to Prestashop and installing it first time can any one tell me   What is mcrypt in Prestashop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an encryption extension which can be used to secure cookies. Prestashop also supports the (legacy) Blowfish method though, so if mcrypt (Rijndael) isn't available on your server, then you can use that instead. I would suggest using mcrypt for all new installs if you can.

Comment: Thanks Paul Campbell i was on leave and could read your answer..thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

mcrypt is a php library

to  install mcrypt on your server :

do this from your ssl client: yum install php-mcrypt